# Javascript to display sharepoint list items on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

With Client Object Model API and a bit of javascript, I want to retrieve the items of a sharepoint list and display them into the web page, **when the web page loads**.

I've successfully implemented examples working with button or link click event handler. But when I try to use the code with `onload` I get an error.

---

Assuming I've my `ViewItem()` function defined in the head.

If I use this code in the body:

```
  <a onclick="javascript:ViewItem()">View</a>
```

all is fine.

If I try with classic `onlaod`, the call fails:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = ViewItem ;
 </script>
```

---

The line of code in `ViewItem` function which generates the error is as follows:

```
   var myContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

This code works fine with the onclick event handler, but fails with the onload event handler with error:

> > *SP.ClientContext is null or not an object*

How can I solve this issue? Why it happens only when the function is called with `onload`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for all SharePoint script to be ready:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ViewItem, "sp.js");
```

If you also use jQuery, I use to do:

```
$(function(){
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ViewItem, "sp.js");
});
```

Comment: God bless you! jQuery works!! I've tried with Javascript but it doesn't, don't know why. The only way to make `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptloaded` work is jQuery. Do you know why?

Comment: I use it with or without jQuery, there may be some issue with other another script in your page.